# Getting all the task list records in outlook instead of user specific

Tags: list, synchronisation

I am working on SharePoint 2010 Task List.

After syncing my task list is connected with Outlook but in the task list all the data will reflect. I want only user specific data.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the `AllItems` view. What you can do it customize the view using Outlook and add a filter based on the `AssignedTo` field.

Also you are do much more using the View Settings. Take a look at this article

http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-tasks-lists-microsoft-outlook/#.VKFQBF4D4